# Imported function won't be recognised inside a template literal

Tags: javascript, webpack

```
import {createTasks} from './app.js';


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {       

 function showNewTaskModal () {

        newTaskModal.classList.add('show');

        const html = `
            <div id="rowrow">
                <input type="text" placeholder="New Task"></input>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Add description"></input>
                <div id="row22">
                    <button>
                        <img src="./Icons/clock.png">
                    </button>
                    
                    <button>
                        <img src="./Icons/star_empty.png">
                    </button>

                    <button onclick="createTasks()">
                        Save
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        `;
    
        newTaskModal.innerHTML = html;

        document.body.appendChild(newTaskModal);
    }
}
```

The createTasks() is recognised everywhere outside the html template literal. I wanna know why not inside it. I encountered below mentioned reference error. I instead of this used setAttribute to add onclick createTasks() to that button and it also didn't work. Why not? **The only approach that works is if I add the html to DOM first, then add an eventlistener to that button**

index.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: createTasks is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:1:1) onclick @ index.html:1

Answer (score 0):

Because the module creates a scope so that functions with similar names of different modules will not cause you trouble:

https://www.showwcase.com/article/27294/module-scope

> In JavaScript, modules have a separate scope distinct from the global scope. This means that variables, functions, and other codes defined within a module are not accessible to code in other modules or the global scope unless explicitly exported. This helps to prevent naming conflicts and makes it easier to organize and reuse code.

So you will need to explicitly export from the module anything that you want to use outside of it. Alternatively you can add it to the global scope, like:

```
import {createTasks} from './app.js';

window.createTasks = createTasks;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {       

 function showNewTaskModal () {

        newTaskModal.classList.add('show');

        const html = `
            <div id="rowrow">
                <input type="text" placeholder="New Task"></input>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Add description"></input>
                <div id="row22">
                    <button>
                        <img src="./Icons/clock.png">
                    </button>
                    
                    <button>
                        <img src="./Icons/star_empty.png">
                    </button>

                    <button onclick="createTasks()">
                        Save
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        `;
    
        newTaskModal.innerHTML = html;

        document.body.appendChild(newTaskModal);
    }
}
```